# no claims info coming through

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, adfs

working on an ADFS asp.net 4.5 application. I have the ADFS working as far as i can tell, i get redirected to my authorization page, get logged in correctly and prompted accordingly if the username or password is wrong. However once i am in, i need to get the logged in users name. I followed the example here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh987037(v=vs.110).aspx but am not getting any claims coming in. Below i will post my code and my web.config. Not sure where to go from here. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please  visit
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433

<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="microsoft.identityModel"   type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration.MicrosoftIdentityModelSection,   Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="PersonnelConnectionString2" connectionString="Data        Source=EXPSQL;Initial Catalog=Personnel;User Id=xxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxx;"     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
 <location path="FederationMetadata">
  <system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
 <!--
For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/? LinkId=235367.

The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
  <system.Web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.Web>
-->
<system.web>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
<authentication mode="None"/>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<pages validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<httpModules>
  <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</httpModules>
</system.web>
<appSettings>
<add key="FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://timeoff.expresslocations.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml"/>
</appSettings>
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<modules>
  <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
  <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
</modules>
</system.webServer>
<microsoft.identityModel>
<service>
  <audienceUris>
    <add value="https://timeoff.expresslocations.com/"/>
  </audienceUris>
  <federatedAuthentication>
    <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://devauth.expresslocations.com/adfs/ls/" realm="https://timeoff.expresslocations.com" requireHttps="true"/>
    <cookieHandler requireSsl="true"/>
  </federatedAuthentication>
  <applicationService>
    <claimTypeRequired>
      <!--Following are the claims offered by STS 'http://devauth.expresslocations.com/adfs/services/trust'. Add or uncomment claims that you require by your application and then update the federation metadata of this application.-->
      <claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" optional="true"/>
      <claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" optional="true"/>
      <claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" optional="true"/>
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname" optional="true" />-->
      <claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn" optional="true"/>
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/CommonName" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/EmailAddress" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group" optional="true" />-->
      <claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/UPN" optional="true"/>
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/privatepersonalidentifier" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationinstant" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationmethod" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/denyonlysid" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/denyonlyprimarysid" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/denyonlyprimarygroupsid" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/primarygroupsid" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/primarysid" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/devicecontext/claims/isregistereduser" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/devicecontext/claims/identifier" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/devicecontext/claims/registrationid" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/devicecontext/claims/displayname" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/devicecontext/claims/ostype" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/devicecontext/claims/osversion" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/devicecontext/claims/ismanaged" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/x-ms-forwarded-client-ip" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/x-ms-client-application" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/x-ms-client-user-agent" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/x-ms-client-ip" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/x-ms-endpoint-absolute-path" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/x-ms-proxy" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/relyingpartytrustid" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/applicationpolicy" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/authoritykeyidentifier" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/basicconstraints" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/eku" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/field/issuer" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/field/issuername" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/keyusage" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/field/notafter" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/field/notbefore" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/certificatepolicy" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/rsa" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/field/rawdata" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/san" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/serialnumber" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/field/signaturealgorithm" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/field/subject" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/subjectkeyidentifier" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/field/subjectname" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/certificatetemplateinformation" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/certificatetemplatename" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/thumbprint" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/field/x509version" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/01/insidecorporatenetwork" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/01/passwordexpirationtime" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/01/passwordexpirationdays" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/01/passwordchangeurl" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/client-request-id" optional="true" />-->
    </claimTypeRequired>
  </applicationService>
  <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
    <trustedIssuers>
      <add thumbprint="A689CD7FDEAB8C0178A8CAC44830D9EE577F6814" name="http://devauth.expresslocations.com/adfs/services/trust"/>
    </trustedIssuers>
  </issuerNameRegistry>
</service>
</microsoft.identityModel>
 </configuration>
```

And the actual code behind:

```
 ClaimsPrincipal cp = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
        if (cp != null)
        {


            foreach (Claim claim in cp.Claims)
            {
                output.InnerText = claim.Type.ToString();

            }
        }
        else
        {
            output.InnerText = "Blank";
        }
```

Comment: In what context are you using the principal? It could be that you are in the wrong part of the ASP.Net request pipeline to get authentication data. Either in BeginRequest or AuthenticateRequest events? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx

Comment: I have the code as the first code in my page load event like in the tutorial. Should i try putting it somewhere else? is that what you are suggesting, or am i missing the point entirely.

Comment: Page_Load should be fine. The 2nd code snippet is missing the method it lives in. My question was more about where it was. If I were to place your code in Global.asax in the BeginRequest method it would most certainly not work. Page_Load is on the Execute handler step of the pipeline, several steps after authentication.

Comment: I see, do you have any idea why my code is not pulling in any claims then?